# open source .NET-based user management systems?

Tags: .net, system

Every business app requires user registration, profile management and an authorization system. I am looking for an open source .net system which I can  usewithout much change. I saw a few in Java but could not found anything useful in .net. What can I use?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework has a lot of this built in, most of which is in System.Web.Security. You should follow the [Quickstarts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt83t3dy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), specifically the "Securing Your Application" one. Login controls and user registrations are included and customizable. There's really no need to add the complexity (and potential security hole) of a third-party solution here.

If you're using MVC, then check out the [relevant section](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-7) of the MVC Music Store tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Check Microsoft’s open-source CMS platform called Orchard

http://www.orchardproject.net/

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) is faily well established and mature. It's the .NET equivalent of PHPNuke.
It's a full blown CMS, but the beauty of it being open source is that you can pull out the bits you want.